# Font not appearing

Tags: css, asp.net, webserver, master-pages, font-face

I am using special fonts for BAR-CODE. it is working perfectly in all pages using a single master page. when I route to another page which is not using that master page the font is not appearing. This is only happening on the web server while in the local host it is working fine. 
In the Head of master page i have this:

```
<link href="App_Themes/Theme1/Mysheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in the CSS file (Mysheet.css) i have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family : IDAutomationHC39M;
    src : url(IDAutomationHC39M.ttf);
}
.BarcodeText      {
    family : IDAutomationHC39M; 
    font-size:large;
}
```

Comment: You have installed the font on your system (localhost)? It would explain why it is working on localhost. If you include the stylesheet only on master page all sides which not going over the master page can not know this font on webserver. Instead standard font will be used. You have to include the stylesheet on the other pages too!

Comment: Sebastian's right. You'll need to make sure the webfont is defined on *all* pages that use it. consider using a top-level master page for this kind of thing.

Comment: In the new page iam using <link href="App_Themes/Theme1/Mysheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: @shomaail that path looks relative. does it actually point to the CSS sheet from where the page is located?

Comment: (consider using the tilde, and `Server.MapPath`: `<link href="<%=Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/Theme1/Mysheet.css"));%>" rel="stylesheet" />`)

Comment: <link href="App_Themes/Theme1/Mysheet.css" rel="stylesheet" /> this is the same in the master page and is working fine there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was resolved by using following tag in the Head of the redirected page

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

this tag was present in the master page as well.